# How to set the ID number to 1 in an Android SQL query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to Query on my table in android SQLite. When I query my table I want the id number to start from 1 and increment for every row. However, when I query on my table at the moment, it's showing the ID number of the original table table. 
Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

```
      private static String[] FROM = {_ID, TITLE, DATE, TIME, DETAILS};
private static String ORDER_BY = TIME + " ASC";

private Cursor getAppointments() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = appointments.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, DATE + "=?", new String[] {date}, null, null, ORDER_BY, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}

}
```

Comment: question is about sqlite then why you tag "mysql"?

Comment: my bad sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you should not really be concerned about the value of the id, other than that it's unique and thus identifies the row.

If you define the table with column **_id** as the **PRIMARY KEY** then unless if you set **_id**, it will normally start with 1 when you insert the first row, the next will normally be 2 and then 3 etc.

If you code **AUTOINCREMENT** though, this may not be the case, as **AUTOINCREMENT** will make the value unique at the database level.

Here's an extract about from [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.
>
> ```
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit
> ```
>
> signed integer.
>
> ```
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
> ```
>
> unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.
>
> ```
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the
> ```
>
> reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
>   purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>   previously deleted rows.

I'm assuming that you don't have an expectation that _id will dynamically change to be the order of the extracted rows after the query, which is how the question could be interpreted as per

> When I query my table I want the id number to start from 1 and
>   increment for every row

If this is your question, then you wouldn't normally do this, rather you'd loop through the cursor, which will be ordered according to the query. If you really wanted the first to be referenced by 1, 2, 3.... then you could loop though the cursor creating an associated array with such a number.

Comment: I get where you're coming from as having the id as a primary key and for it to auto increment is very important for my program. Thank you for the help though, I will try to do the loop through the cursor array idea. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to get the cursor array working. Thank you for the help though.